# Digest loop seems to not be triggered at the end of $http promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to update a variable binded to `$scope` after an ajax promise has been fulfilled, but for some reason the view is not updating once the variable has been changed. When I trigger the digest loop again with an `ng-click` the previous variable finally gets updated. Here is the code:

```
$http.post(location, data).then(function ( res ) {
    $scope.list = JSON.parse(res.data);
    angular.element("#formModal").modal('hide');
}).catch(function ( err ) {
    $log.error(err.statusText);
    $log.error(err.data);
});
```

I am thinking the digest loop didn't get triggered for some reason, but I have no I idea why.

Comment: You don't need to parse response data...it's done internally for you. Likely throwing error in console ...no?

Comment: Pass your error handler function as a second argument to the .then() function, rather than using .catch(). If your success handler function were being called, updating the $scope variable would trigger a digest.

Comment: You are right about not having to parse response data, but doing so did not throw an error. Also passing the error handler as the second argument to the then function, unfortunately, didn't change a thing.